# How can I remove a repositry in Elementary OS 7?

Tags: software-installation, horus

I am experiencing a problem with one repository not having a release file.  For that reason, I would like to remove it, but I can't find the Software and Updates app in the OS to select and remove the repo in the GUI.  How can I remove it in Elementary OS 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Software and Updates app does not (to the best of my knowledge) allow a person to work with the sources list directly in Horus. That said, you can take care of this via the Terminal. Here's how:

0. Open the Terminal application
1. Change to the directory containing `apt`'s `sources.list` file:

   ```
   cd /etc/apt
   ```
2. Edit the `sources.list` file to remove (or comment out) the repository that does not have a release file:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} sources.list
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your preferred text editor.</sup>
3. Find the repo that needs to be removed and add a `#` to the start of the line, or remove it completely.
4. Save the file and exit
5. Update `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

If the repository that you need to remove is not found in `sources.list`, then it will be contained in a file within the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory, possibly in its own definition file.

Comment: Thank you.  The offending repo was for elementary-tweaks and the definition file was in the second location you referenced.  I really appreciate your guidance on this.

Comment: As a sidenote, you can use Pantheon Tweaks for elementary OS 7, https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks/ ; elementary-tweaks is no longer supported